# Loading from file not working.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm taking screenshots and writing them to file with this code:

```
 if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

NSArray *directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [directories objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *key = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"screenshots.archive"];

NSMutableArray *storageArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:key];

if(!storageArray)
    storageArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:data];
else
    [storageArray addObject:data];

[storageArray writeToFile:key atomically:YES];
```

When i load the images again i do this:

```
pics = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath]];

ScreenshotViewController *scv = [[ScreenshotViewController alloc]init];

[[self navigationController]pushViewController:scv animated:YES];
NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
[scv setImage:[pics objectAtIndex:row]];
```

dataFilePath method:

```
- (NSString *)dataFilePath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"screenshots.archive"];
}
```

The problem is that that the UIImageView, in the ScreenshotViewController remains blank. I have tested all kinds of things, and it is something about the way the images get saved/loaded into the array, but i'm not sure. I have also tested that the actual screenshot part is working by putting it into a UIImageView right away and adding it to the view.

NOTE:
If i change this

```
[scv setImage:[pics objectAtIndex:row]];
```

to this

```
[scv.myUIImageView setImage:[pics objectAtIndex:row]];
```

i get this exception: [__NSCFData _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x847a280.

Whats the correct way of setting the image by?

Wow it got abit messy, hope its readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, and assuming your read/write code is correct, you are saving the image with PNG representation.
Thus, when reading, you will need to create a UIImage like this:

```
UIImage * myPic = [UIImage imageWithData:[pics objectAtIndex:row]];
```

Then try showing that image